# Placing small image over background color html?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, css-tables

I need to overlay a small arrow on top of a background color in a div. However, only the image appears and not the background color. This is my CSS:

```
table.dataTable thead .rand {
      background-color: #FFFF66;
  background: url("testing.png") no-repeat center right;
}
```

I think the second background statement overwrites the one above it which causes the color to not show. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the background shorthand syntax is overriding your background color rule. Combine them:

```
background: #ff6 url("testing.png") no-repeat center right;
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order they occur in the css.